# How to make Asynchronous http request using python grequests

Tags: python, asynchronous, grequests

I am not able to get the asynchronous property out of this code.  The calling url has a sleep of 10 seconds.

The grequests.send command finishes immediately but I am not getting the request at the server.

If I am using r.send() or grequests.map(), the request getting blocked for 10 seconds which I do not expect.

```
import grequests
url = 'http://localhost:9000/test'
r = grequests.post(url)
grequests.send(r, grequests.Pool(1))
```

Please Help. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the actual traffic with, for instance, [Wireshark](http://wireshark.org)? It will help you to see whether the query is sent, if you get a reply,  etc.

Comment: @WoJ , I am able to call from browser as well as make blocking request.  The issue here is I am not able to make unblocking request.

Comment: I understand and this was clear from your a comment of yours. My comment was about checking what happens, traffic-wise, when you do an asynchronous call (so that you can try to see where the blocking comes from: the code (no packets are sent for instance), the infrastructure (sent packets are misshaped and rejected by an intermediate equipment, or the card itself), ...)

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like it could be that port 9000 is blocked (e.g., through UFW or iptables).  If you are using Windows, I would open Fiddler and try again.  If you are using Linux, I'd install nmap.

```
nmap -p 9000 localhost
```

A result of "filtered" means that the port is blocked.  A result of "closed" or "open" means the port is not blocked.

In your Python code, you may want to have brackets [] around the URL with single quotes.  You may also want to replace "url" with "urls".

Comment: The port is opened. I am able to make synchronous requests. Even I am able to make requests through browser.  -Thanks.